# Reading multiple csv files into separate dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have read multiple answers but none have worked in my case so far. I want to read multiple csv files (which may not be in the same directory as my python file), without specifying names (as I may have to read thousands of such files). I want to do something like the last example in [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-dataframes-in-python/) but I am not sure how to add my desktop path.

I tried the following, as given in the link:

```
# Assign path. The folder "Healthy" contains all the csv files
path, dirs, files = next(os.walk("/Users/my_name/Desktop/All hypnograms/Healthy"))
file_count = len(files)
# create empty list
dataframes_list = []
 
# append datasets to the list
for i in range(file_count):
    temp_df = pd.read_csv("./csv/"+files[i])
    dataframes_list.append(temp_df)
```

However, I got the following error: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:". I am using MAC OS. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: You are using `os.walk` ..., can csv files exist in subdirectories of this directory?

Comment: I can import them but I wanted an algorithm to read it from any folder that I want.

Comment: Was that an answer to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `path` is the root of each file in `files`, so you can do

```
temp_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, files[i]))
```

But we really wouldn't do it this way. Suppose there aren't any files in the directory, then `next(os.walk("/Users/my_name/Desktop/All hypnograms/Healthy"))` would raise a `StopIteration` error that you don't handle. I think it would be more natural to use `os.listdir`, `glob.glob` or even `pathlib.Path`. Since `pathlib` keeps track of the root for you, a good choice is

```
from pathlib import Path 
import pandas as pd

healthy = Path("/Users/my_name/Desktop/All hypnograms/Healthy")
dataframes_list = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in healthy.iterdir()
    if file.is_file()]
```

Many pandas errors inherit from `ValueError`. If you have problems with some files, you can put the read into an exception handler to find out which files are in error

```
dataframes_list = []
error_files = []

for file in helthy.iterdir():
    if file.is_file():
        try:
            dataframes_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=18))
        except ValueError as e:
            error_files.append(file)
            print(f"{file}: {e}")
```

Comment: It's giving me the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte

Comment: That means that the file doesn't use the same encoding as the default selected by pandas. Do you know the encoding?  You could try `encoding="cp1252"` or `encoding="latin-1"` in the `read_csv` call.

Comment: encoding="cp1252" worked! But in my read_csv(), I need to also skip the first 18 rows of each csv file. If in your code, I write pd.read_csv(file, encoding="cp1252",skiprows=18) it gives me the error "EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file". Do you know if I can achieve this here?

Comment: Sounds like there were only 18 lines or perhaps the first remaining line was an empty line.

Comment: If I am reading just one csv file with skiprows = 18, it works perfectly fine. There are over a thousand rows.

Comment: I added an example that would at least tell you which files fail. This code isn't checking whether this is really a csv (it doesn't even check the file extension) so there could be non-csv files in there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should specify the whole path in `read_csv` method by adding the path variable to the concatenated string. Something like :

```
for i in range(file_count):
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(path + "/csv/" + files[i])
    dataframes_list.append(temp_df)
```

You can remove the `"/csv/"` by doing `path + files[i]` directly if your CSV files are in the Healthy directory

Comment: It doesn't work, it is giving me the same error.

Comment: Which folder contains all your csv files? Can you provide a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib` to do that easily:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path.home() / 'Desktop' / 'All hypnograms' / 'Healthy' / 'csv'

dataframes_list = []
for csvfile in DATA_DIR.glob('**/*.csv'):
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    dataframes_list.append(temp_df)
```

Comment: When I run dataframes_list, it's giving me an empty list [].

Comment: Is DATA_DIR path exists? Just try `print(list(DATA_DIR.glob('**/*.*')))`. The output is correct?

Comment: It's giving me an empty list []

Comment: Ok. so simply use `print(list(pathlib.Path("/Users/my_name/Desktop/All hypnograms/Healthy").glob('**/*.*')))`

Comment: You have to fix the path according the location of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want indeed to filter the files list by excluding non `.csv` files in order to use the pandas method `read_csv` :

**Proposed code to execute :**

Like you do not provide dataframe to work with I voluntarily excluded `pd.read_csv` but you would have to use `pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, f))` in real code.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Let'us suppose path and files following values
path = '/home/Motors'
files = ['engine.html', 'engine.csv']

dataframes_list=[]

for f in files:
    if Path(f).suffixes[0]=='.csv':
        # temp_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, f))
        temp_df = os.path.join(path, f)
        dataframes_list.append(temp_df)
print(dataframes_list)
```

**Result :**

```
['/home/Motors/engine.csv']
```

**To answer to S C comment:**

What you should do is, as a first step, create a an iterator containing all the names.
And after that to read it by chunks to make short listnames to process.

```py
filenames = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']

def iterchunks(filenames, n):
    for i in range(0, len(filenames), n):
        yield filenames[i:i + n]

chk = iterchunks(filenames, n=2)

print(next(chk))       
# ['A', 'B']

print(next(chk))       
# ['C', 'D']
```

Comment: I do not want to write the names of the files. There are hundreds of csv files that I need to read. Writing all the names of all the files isn't feasible, as mentioned in my question.